# Asynchronous request to fetch data from Facebook in a Python app

Tags: python, facebook, oauth, flask, oauth-2.0

I'm explopring a little bit Python and try to implement manually a Facebook
login flow in  Flask application. 
I'm using a Python rauth library for OAuth part. I have problem with the last part, because from what I know, **the code with the part of requesting to exchange code for an access token and retrieve user's data should be performed asynchronous**. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this correctly. For now, it looks as follows:

This is the function that I want to run in a separate thread:

```
 def callback(self):
        if 'code' not in request.args:
            return None, None, None, None
        oauth_session = self.service.get_auth_session(
                data={'code': request.args['code'],
                      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                      'redirect_uri': self.get_callback_url()})
        me = oauth_session.get('me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name').json()
        return (
            me['id'],
            me.get('email'),
            me.get('first_name'),
            me.get('last_name')
        )
```

and I invoke it here:

```
...    
...
    oauth = FacebookSignIn()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=oauth)
    thread.start()
    facebook_id, email, first_name, last_name = oauth.callback()
    print "Waiting..."
    thread.join()
    print "Complete"
....
```

But I guess it still doesn't change anything. I have to probably check in some way if it's done or something. Could You please show me, how it should be done ?